# Tree Table With Angular ngRepeat

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

We need to display some tabular data according to a hierarchy. For example a list of country with their population and the area they cover, along with some of their cities. It could go to deeper levels as well such as neiborhood, etc.

```
Place        Population    Area
---------------------------------
Canada      33,500,000     10,000,000
  Toronto    2,600,000         612
  Montreal   1,300,000         300
USA         317,000,000     9,800,000
  ...          ...             ...
  ...          ...             ...
     ...       ...             ...           
     ...       ...             ...
```

I've tried to used Angular and ngRepeat to create a Tree table to display this hierarchy but it doesn't work. I also tried this nice solution from Brendan Owen http://jsfiddle.net/brendanowen/uXbn6/8/ that uses ul and li tags but it doesn't work either when table and tr/td tags are used. Is it possible to accomplish this for a table?

Comment: basic table layout like that is not difficult with ng repeat...provide a demo in plunker or jsfiddle.net showing where your problems are. Complexity will be determined by features wanted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst it doesn't use a HTML table, have you checked out the [angular dynamic-tree](https://github.com/jvmvik/angular-demo/tree/master/dynamic-tree)?

It may also be worth checking out the blog post which [spawned it](http://blog.boxelderweb.com/2013/08/19/angularjs-a-lazily-loaded-recursive-tree-widget/), since there is a little less code to digest there.

If you are looking for an example, here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/immersion/c9Ecb/).
Where your html would simply become something like:

```
<ui-tree
    ng-model="assets"
    load-fn="loadChildren"
    expand-to="hierarchy"
    selected-id="111"
    attr-node-id="assetId" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This project offers good Angular tree with a good following (435+ starred).

https://github.com/nickperkinslondon/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree

A sample of the tree can be found here.
http://nickperkinslondon.github.io/angular-bootstrap-nav-tree/test/bs3_ng120_test_page.html

For non-Angular option, jquery treetable does offer a fairly easy implementation.

http://ludo.cubicphuse.nl/jquery-treetable/

Each node (parent, child or subsequent children) needs to be a tr element in table, needing to specify id of its own and of the parent node.

```
<table>
    <tr data-tt-id="1">
        <td>Parent</td>
    </tr>
    <tr data-tt-id="2" data-tt-parent-id="1">
        <td>Child</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```